# Android Studio replaced code in my main.dart file

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

### **I re-opened Android Studio and founded that the code in my main.dart file had been replaced with this**

---

```
 /*
     * Copyright 2010 the original author or authors.
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */
    package org.gradle.api.specs;
    
    import com.google.common.collect.Iterators;
    
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    
    /**
     * A {@link org.gradle.api.specs.Spec} which aggregates a sequence of other {@code Spec} instances.
     *
     * @param <T> The target type for this Spec
     */
    public abstract class CompositeSpec<T> implements Spec<T> {
        private static final Spec<?>[] EMPTY = new Spec[0];
    
        private final Spec<
```

---

### **I have tried inavalidating caches and restarting but that did not work. Any reason this happened or possible fix?**

Answer (score 0):

option 1 -> u can delete this dart file and use old dart file or u can stash ur code if u have only this file changes.
option 2 -> if it is auto generated delete build folder from app directory.